# SQLite time difference calculations in HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sqlite, datetime, time, difference

How to calculate time difference in HH:MM:SS format in SQLite?

`SELECT time(strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28') - strftime('%s','2017-11-01'));`
 gives me:

> 12:00:00

and

`SELECT datetime(strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28') - strftime('%s','2017-11-01'));`
 gives me:

> -4492-12-04 12:00:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), numbers are interpreted as Julian date numbers by default.

If your value is a number of seconds, you have to interpret it as a number of seconds, i.e., as a Unix timestamp:

```
SELECT time(strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28') - strftime('%s','2017-11-01'), 'unixepoch');
```